# Having trouble displaying API results

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I'm learning API's and I am using https://calendarific.com api and I have fetched the api and am able to console log the results. My problem is actually displaying the result of the api.

I have tried to save the name to a variable (like this)

```
myVariable.innerHTML = data.name;
```

myVariable holds an object with nested arrays:
{holidays: [Arrays]} but I'm having trouble displaying it.

If it helps here is my code:

```
  let countrySelect = document.getElementById('country-select');
  let holidayName = document.querySelector('holiday-name')
  let holidayDesc = document.querySelector('holiday-desc')


  const api = `https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?api_key=<my api key>&country=ca&year=2019`;


// Get results on click
countrySelect.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fetch(api)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
   })
    .then(data => {
      holidayName = data.response;
      console.log(data)
    });
  })
```

Comment: Can we see the results of the `console.log` method? Also, `document.querySelector('holiday-desc')` shouldn't be working since you haven't specified if it's a `class` or a `id`.

Comment: Like @Manuel said, plus `holidayName = data.response` is wrong. Should be `holidayName.innerHTML = data`

Comment: Can you post your `HTML` code?

Comment: @Mauel Abascal When I console log the data it returns the api response.                                                                     @kedar here is the html`<div class="country-select" id="country-select">
        <button id="option0" value="ca">Canada</button>
     </div>

  <div id="responseField">
    <h1 class="holiday-name"></h1>
    <p class="holiday-desc"></p>
  </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var btn = document.querySelector('#option0');
 var holiday = document.querySelector('holiday-name');
 var holidayDesc = document.querySelector('holiday-desc');

btn.addEventListener('click', function fetchApi(){
    fetch('https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?api_key=<my api key>&country=ca&year=2019')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
       holiday.innerHTML = data.response.holidays[0].name;
        //console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Hope this helps